# SFML 2.1 / C++ accept user text in game

Tags: c++, keyboard, sfml, keyboard-events

I am having issues and searched the internet for this but haven't found really what I am looking for.

I also figured this would be a question many other beginners would have.

What I am wanting to do is give the user, a text box to enter text into, for example their name. I have searched through the SFML documents but haven't found anything yet.

So what I need to my understanding is to... Accept key and save it to string. I know how to do this if I manually check each:

```
 sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)
 text += "A"
```

but I am looking for one that returns the key pressed instead of checking each key individually?

Comment: just poll events and check if key is pressed, if it is, you can already read the key code from the event struct. For text, use TextEntered event tho, because KeyPressed is not the same(á would say I pressed 8 on my keyboard, but TextEntered will say á).

Comment: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/window-events.php#the-textentered-event explains it well I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both comments below the initial question were perfect! If you look at the documentation, there is perfect explanations and examples:

just poll events and check if key is pressed, if it is, you can already read the key code from the event struct. For text, use TextEntered event tho, because KeyPressed is not the same(á would say I pressed 8 on my keyboard, but TextEntered will say á). –  Creris 17 mins ago

sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/… explains it well I think. –  Hiura 6 mins ago

Thanks!